# How to organise with other parents at school

Tags: school, politics

Last March when the Covid-19 pandemic reached my country, at some schools the parents had organized and told the school as a group they were not letting their kids come in on Monday. This did not happen in our school, as far as I know.

About a year ago there was also a situation (proposed change in the school board many parents disagreed with) where parents could have organised but to the best of my knowledge did not. The unwanted change fell through, as far as I could tell because many individual parents had made it clear they did not agree.

This autumn Covid-19 will likely spike again and I think it is important to at least have decent ventilation in the classrooms. This question is **not** about Covid-19!
How could I start organizing with other parents, on an informal basis, to make sure this is handled well?

I know very little about air-quality control, apparently the amount of fresh air is a setting and more fresh air means more cold air that will have to be heated.
In other words: better ventilation will cost more money. I am prepared to pay for this, but it is something to consider when organizing with other parents. We may well end up crowd-funding this between ourselves.

My contacts with other parents until now, 3 years in, have been with the parents and the grandparents my kid plays with after school. With 2 sets of parents I sometimes have coffee, while our kids play. That is it.

How do I find out if some parents are already organized somehow, and if not how do I start this myself?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of different opinions on what you could do. I am dealing with something similar right now at my two daughters' school. We live in a low-income community and the school has been shut down many times. Lastly, there were not enough teachers and not enough buses to take the high schoolers to the only high school they could attend, which is 20 minutes away in the city. The parents had to find them their rides. Can you imagine? Anyway, this is what I suggest...

1. Find out from the school if there is an app or website where parents can stay connected with their child's teacher. Our school used the Class Dojo app, and it listed every kid in their class and that kid's parents' name. On Class Dojo, you could also communicate in a group chat with all the parents and that's an effective way to get their phone numbers or to just find out who they are. I added a lot of parents on Facebook this way.
2. I found a lot of information going on in my town by attending the parent-student body. We would mention issues we had and try to resolve them the best way we could. If we couldn't afford something we would look to the town for sponsors, grants, or fundraising.
3. You mentioned your kid hangs out with some kids from school and you have coffee with them. Mention to them you want to be more involved with what's going on with the parents, teachers, etc. They may know more people and you could have them ask if you could contact them.
4. One of the biggest things you could do is once you get more parents' names and if they want to be involved, you could start a Facebook page. That way you could add the parents you know and in return those parents could add the parents they know. They don't all have to be in the same class or grade. They could be parents of kids who play sports, do chorus or band, or are a part of the school council.

Hope some of this helps you because it was hard getting the names of the parents that weren't in my kid's classes because they don't list them on that app Class Dojo. Other parents helped me with that. Wish you the best of luck!